# crash when open zoom in ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu

[I just installed Ubuntu Studio 22.04 and for some strange reason Zoom client crashes on start. Not sure if it's just me or if this is a common problem across. I installed zoom client downloaded from their official website. After installing when I open it just crashes.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVMMo.png)

Answer (score 1):

you can try the command=

1.`sudo apt update`

2.`sudo snap install zoom-client`

3.`sudo apt upgrade`

4.Launch the zoom `zoom-client`